# Why is SSH forwarding happening even with port forwarding disabled?

Tags: security, ssh, airport

I am using an Aiport Extreme as my wireless router, and it has port forwarding set up but disabled for SSH:
[image: Screen shot of my configuration window]
[image: The port forward settings sheet]

However, I keep seeing instances of ssh login attempts from outside -- someone is trying to access my computer using a series of user names. Moreover, I can still log in from outside my home network using SSH, so I know it's open to the world.

How is this happening? How do I stop it?

### Edit

Here is the log for a connection attempt:

```
==> /var/log/system.log <==
Apr 10 10:36:41: --- last message repeated 8 times ---
Apr 10 10:36:41 null-3 sandboxd[56246]: sshd(68515) deny mach-per-user-lookup

==> /var/log/secure.log <==
Apr 10 10:36:43 null-3 sshd[68516]: Invalid user presto from 124.124.91.195
```

Comment: Can you post the log entry for one of the ssh attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure when you select remote log in in the sharing preference pane, OS X opens the port on the router programmatically using NAT-PMP. Have you tried disabling that on the airport and rebooting?

[image: Turn off NAT-PMP]

Also be sure you are not editing a profile that is not active on the Airport. I have fallen into that trap once or twice every so often.

Comment: That'd be a pain; I have other services that use this. I'll have to experiment to see if that's the case.

Comment: It's the answer to why - as you note, you could do it temporarily for testing to make sure it's the case. Then you can look into http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~greg/sshdfilter/ to cut off hosts that try to brute force your mac.

Comment: I ended up installing sshdfilter. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I would turn off your remote access until you know your home network isn't public so that someone doesn't access it besides you.

Comment: No can do; I need ssh access to the machine, just not so much from outside.

Comment: You may be able to set up password on your AirPort Extreme router, I know that many programs written for wireless connection require set passwords in order to attempt the connection you might be able to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Airport Extreme admin but it looks like you have SSH remote login turned off in the first dialog, and then in the second dialog add it manually mapping external port 22 to internal ip 191.168.1.10 port 22. What you are seeing is someone (usually a script kiddie) trying a dictionary attack against your system.

If you must have ssh access then I would suggest running it on a non standard external port, which you map to the internal address and port 22. On Linux boxes to prevent this type of activity I normally install [DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/index.html) which seems to have a Mac port available. This monitors the logs of the ssh daemon, and adds the ip of any system that had a configurable number of failed login attempts within a time window to /etc/hosts.deny

Comment: The second screen shot is a detail of the first; it's the view of the disabled SSH setting in that dialog.